# Identical network printers: find the right one

Tags: networking, printing

I need to install a network printer Kyocera ECOSYS M2035dn in Kubuntu 16.04. There are several identical printers in our local network:

[image]

[image]

In file properties, there is no IP address of these devices:

[image]

When I try to add a printer through CUPS page, there is also no information about ip address:

[image]

I could try adding all printers and print the test page, but I don't want to disturb my colleagues. How can I add a printer, knowing its IP address?

Comment: KM3C991.local seems to be the name of your printer, try the command `ping -c1 KM3C991.local`, it should show the ip of the printer.

Comment: Oh thank you! All printers are pinged well, and now I can find my printer. You can make this an answer, I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KM3C991.local is the name of your printer on your network.

`ping -c1 KM3C991.local` will show you the IP address of the printer.